# Jquery tags input plugin styling

Tags: jquery, tags

I use this: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

as a plugin for an autocompletition.

I want some of the fields in the combobox to be bold.

This is the data in the combobox:

```
john, jackson, tom, <b>peter</b>, alex
```

And I want peter to be bold.

However, it isn't. When I go inspect element, it shows  < b > peter < / b >, but when I go edit as html, the editor for the source code is opened and it shows html encoding for < b > and < /b >: & l t ; b & g t ; bold & l t ; / b & g t ;

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of patch solution i came with:
After I built my dom.. I changed the innerHTML of the element.
Of course you can manipulate with the elements like comparing the strings and so on..

```
<input id="tag1" value="alpha,beta,gamma,delta">    
<input id="someOtherId" value="peter,jackson">

var arr = $('#tag1_tagsinput span.tag');
var arr2 = $('#someOtherId_tagsinput span.tag');

var spanChild = arr[2].getElementsByTagName('span');
spanChild[0].innerHTML = "<b>"+spanChild[0].innerHTML+"</b>";
```

Comment: Where in the code do you call this? In $(function() { ... }) ?

Comment: I call to this after $('#tag1').tagsInput(); and it worked for me

Comment: How can this work for you when $('#tag1_tagsinput span.tag') is undefined?

Comment: #tag1 is the id you give to your input tag.

Comment: Of course you need to run this in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Did you add jQuery in head section in html?

Comment: Yes. In your example the items peter, jackson are given in the definition. I load them as json.